# Jquery Scroll plugin with click and scroll support simultaneously

Tags: jquery, wordpress, scroll, click

I need to build a scoll page exactly like this.
http://twentyninepalms.ca/script.
When I click on next scene the script container should get scrolled to next scene. If I scroll the page and than click on next scene it should get me to the next scene.
I have tried but not succeed to get desired functionality.
So far what I have tried is this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".nxt_scene a").click(function(e) {   

   e.preventDefault();

   var i = $("#scenes .scene.selected").next().offset().top;
   var main_offset=i-58;
   $('.mCSB_container').animate({   

        top: "-"+main_offset+"px"

    },1000);

   $("#scenes .scene.selected").removeClass("selected").next().addClass("selected");


});});
```

I can not use demo site jquery because in this site code is fetched into js from json data but in my case is wordpress.
Can you please help me or suggest me some jquery plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You shoudl use `offset().top` and `scrollTop`.

---

Get already scrolled value, and next scene offset position to top :

```
var scrolledScenes = $(".container").scrollTop();
var nextOffset = $(".scene.active").next(".scene").offset().top + scrolledScenes;
```

Now set params for the `scrollTop` animation :

```
var speed = 750; // Animation speed (ms)
$('.container').animate({
    scrollTop: nextOffset
}, speed); // Go
```

And update active scene status for the new next scene :

```
$(".active").removeClass("active").next(".scene").addClass("active");
```

---

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="scenes">
        <div class="scene active">
            <p><strong>Scene 1</strong> - Et hanc quidem praeter oppida multa duae civitates exornant Seleucia opus Seleuci regis, et Claudiopolis quam deduxit coloniam Claudius Caesar. Isaura enim antehac nimium potens, olim subversa ut rebellatrix interneciva aegre vestigia claritudinis pristinae monstrat admodum pauca.</p>
            <p>Haec igitur lex in amicitia sanciatur, ut neque rogemus res turpes nec faciamus rogati. Turpis enim excusatio est et minime accipienda cum in ceteris peccatis, tum si quis contra rem publicam se amici causa fecisse fateatur. Etenim eo loco, Fanni et Scaevola, locati sumus ut nos longe prospicere oporteat futuros casus rei publicae. Deflexit iam aliquantum de spatio curriculoque consuetudo maiorum.</p>
            <p>Soleo saepe ante oculos ponere, idque libenter crebris usurpare sermonibus, omnis nostrorum imperatorum, omnis exterarum gentium potentissimorumque populorum, omnis clarissimorum regum res gestas, cum tuis nec contentionum magnitudine nec numero proeliorum nec varietate regionum nec celeritate conficiendi nec dissimilitudine bellorum posse conferri; nec vero disiunctissimas terras citius passibus cuiusquam potuisse peragrari, quam tuis non dicam cursibus, sed victoriis lustratae sunt.</p>
            <p>Hanc regionem praestitutis celebritati diebus invadere parans dux ante edictus per solitudines Aboraeque amnis herbidas ripas, suorum indicio proditus, qui admissi flagitii metu exagitati ad praesidia descivere Romana. absque ullo egressus effectu deinde tabescebat immobilis.</p>
            <p>Et eodem impetu Domitianum praecipitem per scalas itidem funibus constrinxerunt, eosque coniunctos per ampla spatia civitatis acri raptavere discursu. iamque artuum et membrorum divulsa conpage superscandentes corpora mortuorum ad ultimam truncata deformitatem velut exsaturati mox abiecerunt in flumen.</p>
            <p>Nam sole orto magnitudine angusti gurgitis sed profundi a transitu arcebantur et dum piscatorios quaerunt lenunculos vel innare temere contextis cratibus parant, effusae legiones, quae hiemabant tunc apud Siden, isdem impetu occurrere veloci. et signis prope ripam locatis ad manus comminus conserendas denseta scutorum conpage semet scientissime praestruebant, ausos quoque aliquos fiducia nandi vel cavatis arborum truncis amnem permeare latenter facillime trucidarunt.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="scene">
            <p><strong>Scene 2</strong> - Post hanc adclinis Libano monti Phoenice, regio plena gratiarum et venustatis, urbibus decorata magnis et pulchris; in quibus amoenitate celebritateque nominum Tyros excellit, Sidon et Berytus isdemque pares Emissa et Damascus saeculis condita priscis.</p>
            <p>Mensarum enim voragines et varias voluptatum inlecebras, ne longius progrediar, praetermitto illuc transiturus quod quidam per ampla spatia urbis subversasque silices sine periculi metu properantes equos velut publicos signatis quod dicitur calceis agitant, familiarium agmina tamquam praedatorios globos post terga trahentes ne Sannione quidem, ut ait comicus, domi relicto. quos imitatae matronae complures opertis capitibus et basternis per latera civitatis cuncta discurrunt.</p>
            <p>Equitis Romani autem esse filium criminis loco poni ab accusatoribus neque his iudicantibus oportuit neque defendentibus nobis. Nam quod de pietate dixistis, est quidem ista nostra existimatio, sed iudicium certe parentis; quid nos opinemur, audietis ex iuratis; quid parentes sentiant, lacrimae matris incredibilisque maeror, squalor patris et haec praesens maestitia, quam cernitis, luctusque declarat.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="scene">
            <p><strong>Scene 3</strong> - Et est admodum mirum videre plebem innumeram mentibus ardore quodam infuso cum dimicationum curulium eventu pendentem. haec similiaque memorabile nihil vel serium agi Romae permittunt. ergo redeundum ad textum.</p>
            <p>Equitis Romani autem esse filium criminis loco poni ab accusatoribus neque his iudicantibus oportuit neque defendentibus nobis. Nam quod de pietate dixistis, est quidem ista nostra existimatio, sed iudicium certe parentis; quid nos opinemur, audietis ex iuratis; quid parentes sentiant, lacrimae matris incredibilisque maeror, squalor patris et haec praesens maestitia, quam cernitis, luctusque declarat.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="scene">
            <p><strong>Scene 4</strong> - Et est admodum mirum videre plebem innumeram mentibus ardore quodam infuso cum dimicationum curulium eventu pendentem. haec similiaque memorabile nihil vel serium agi Romae permittunt. ergo redeundum ad textum.</p>
            <p>Equitis Romani autem esse filium criminis loco poni ab accusatoribus neque his iudicantibus oportuit neque defendentibus nobis. Nam quod de pietate dixistis, est quidem ista nostra existimatio, sed iudicium certe parentis; quid nos opinemur, audietis ex iuratis; quid parentes sentiant, lacrimae matris incredibilisque maeror, squalor patris et haec praesens maestitia, quam cernitis, luctusque declarat.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="scene">
            <p><strong>Scene 5</strong> - Et est admodum mirum videre plebem innumeram mentibus ardore quodam infuso cum dimicationum curulium eventu pendentem. haec similiaque memorabile nihil vel serium agi Romae permittunt. ergo redeundum ad textum.</p>
            <p>Equitis Romani autem esse filium criminis loco poni ab accusatoribus neque his iudicantibus oportuit neque defendentibus nobis. Nam quod de pietate dixistis, est quidem ista nostra existimatio, sed iudicium certe parentis; quid nos opinemur, audietis ex iuratis; quid parentes sentiant, lacrimae matris incredibilisque maeror, squalor patris et haec praesens maestitia, quam cernitis, luctusque declarat.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="scene">
            <p><strong>Scene 6</strong> - Et est admodum mirum videre plebem innumeram mentibus ardore quodam infuso cum dimicationum curulium eventu pendentem. haec similiaque memorabile nihil vel serium agi Romae permittunt. ergo redeundum ad textum.</p>
            <p>Equitis Romani autem esse filium criminis loco poni ab accusatoribus neque his iudicantibus oportuit neque defendentibus nobis. Nam quod de pietate dixistis, est quidem ista nostra existimatio, sed iudicium certe parentis; quid nos opinemur, audietis ex iuratis; quid parentes sentiant, lacrimae matris incredibilisque maeror, squalor patris et haec praesens maestitia, quam cernitis, luctusque declarat.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="nxt_scene">Next Scene</div>
```

---

CSS :

```
.container {
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
.scene {
    border-top:1px dashed #999;
    padding:10px;
}
.scene:first-child {
    border-top:none;
}
.nxt_scene {
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
    background:#cecece;
    border:1px solid #999;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

> [» Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wpj6uepo/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will give it try for sure